# Google Maps API v3 remove all polylines

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, polyline

Little background. I have a navigation setup for when you click on a certain navigation item, it creates `markers` on the map. If you click on a different navigation item, it removes the previous `markers` and sets up new ones.

Well now I am working with `polylines` and trying to create the same concept here with the `polylines`, however I am having a difficult time. Here is what I have:

```
    // Global variable for array of lines
    var points= [];
```

Setup my points.

```
    line1 = new google.maps.LatLng(line1Start, line1Finish);
    line2 = new google.maps.LatLng(line2Start, line2Finish);
    line3 = new google.maps.LatLng(line3Start,line3Finish);

    points.push(line1, line2, line3);
```

Setup my polylines.

```
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path:points,
       strokeColor:"#FF0000",
       strokeOpacity:1.0,
       strokeWeight:2
    });
```

Initialize the map with lines.

```
    polyline.setMap(map);
```

All works well.  The lines are created and show up between my markers. Now lets remove them (or not...)

```
    function removeLines() {
      if (points) {
           points.length = 0;
      }
      points = [];
    }
```

removeLines() is being called at the beginning of the function to clear them, then new ones are setup. This indeed clears my points in the points array, however on the map itself the `polylines` still show up and do not disappear like my markers do.

What gives?!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to do `polyline.setMap(null)`, that will remove the line from the map. [Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline).

Comment: Wow.. I was doing this before, however I was doing a loop on the points array and doing points[i].setMap(null); Obviously this needs to be on the polyline and not the points array... DUH. +1 thanks for helping me realize that :)

Comment: How did you get it?I try line.setMap(null) to remove lines and then line.setMap(this.map) to set new lines and doesn´t work.

Answer (score 22):

polyline is just an array of LatLng objects, not individual Polylines. I think you probably need a separate array for the polylines, which you can then loop over to remove them all. Create a global array line.

```
 var line = [];
 polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: points,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
 line.push(polyline);
```

Now you are pushing all the polyline objects into an array line. You can make it invisible or remove it from the map by looping it like this:

```
for (i=0; i<line.length; i++) 
{                           
  line[i].setMap(null); //or line[i].setVisible(false);
}
```