# How to remove polylines of google maps api 3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can someone tell me why I can't remove my polylines with this code:

```
    $("#chkRouteLines").click(function () {

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: positions,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        visible: true
    }); ;

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        polyline.setMap(map);
    } else {
        polyline.setMap(null);
    }
})
```

I found in the documentation of google maps api 3 that I need to do: setMap(null)..
But this didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511474/google-maps-api-v3-remove-all-polylines

Comment: Maybe read the question. I said setMap(null) didn't work here. I also read that SO question before.

Comment: why would the same api work sometimes and not others?  do you get errors?  Also, why do you have 2 semi colons after your polyline var is setup?

Comment: no errors, I can see the lines, but I can't remove them.

Comment: You're going to need to post the full code for the page or a link to it. I suspect it is a different polyline that you see. How did you get the polyline plotted in the first place? With the DirectionsRenderer perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't retaining a reference to the polyline, it is local to the "$("#chkRouteLines").click" function.  If you have *one* polyline, make the reference to it global.

```
var polyline = null; // in the global scope

$("#chkRouteLines").click(function () {
    if (!polyline || !polyline.setMap) {
      polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: positions,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        visible: true
      }); 
    }

if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    polyline.setMap(map);
} else {
    polyline.setMap(null);
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk1bdth3/)

If you need to add and remove multiple different polylines, an array usually works.

code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var polyline;

positions = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.441883,-122.143019),
             new google.maps.LatLng(37.45296,-122.181725)];
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    
    $("#chkRouteLines").click(function () {
        if (!polyline || !polyline.setMap) {
          polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: positions,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            visible: true
          }); 
        }

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        polyline.setMap(map);
    } else {
        polyline.setMap(null);
    }
})


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<input id="chkRouteLines" value="click" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: You're going to need to post the full code for the page or a link to it. I suspect it is a different polyline that you see. How did you get the polyline plotted in the first place? With the DirectionsRenderer perhaps?

Comment: Initialize Polyline object after you initialize map object, both in same scope of function. And then , In your onclick function just call setMap function with your arguments. This way your map will have a single Polyline object and you won't loose its reference before clearing it from map. This solution working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

polyline is just an array of LatLng objects, not individual Polylines. I think you probably need a separate array for the Polylines, which you can then loop over to remove them all. Create a global array line.

```
 var line = [];
 polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: positions,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        map: map
    });
 line.push(flightPath);
```

Now you are pushing all the polyline objects into an array line. You can make it invisible or remove it from the map by looping it like this:

```
for (i=0; i<line.length; i++) 
{                           
  line[i].setMap(null); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In example [Remove a Polyline Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove), See that they created global variable `flightPath` and initialized it in function initialize with `Polyline` object. This way we don't loose its reference on button click.So by using the code        `flightPath.setMap(null);` the hide the `Polyline` from `map`.

In your example , you are 
initializing `polyline` on `click` event, so you overwrite previous `Polyline` object reference and this is why it is not hiding when you call `polyline.setMap(null);` Follow the given example to make it right.